# Converting a string array from WWW to a class list in Unity3d

Tags: c#, arrays, list, converters

I am having some trouble converting a WWW string array to a class list. What I want to do is instantiate a prefab which has a number of text elements in it.
Here is the base class

```
public class VehicleIndex : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public string ID{ get; set;}
    public string Make{ get; set;}
    public string Model{ get; set;}
    public string Year{ get; set;}
    public string Mileage{ get; set;}


    public VehicleIndex(string id, string make, string model, string year, string mileage)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Make = make;
        this.Model = model;
        this.Year = year;
        this.Mileage = mileage;
    }



}
```

Here is the function that gets the WWW data from the Mysql database

```
    public List<VehicleIndex> VehicleIndexList = new List<VehicleIndex> ();
    public string[] VehicleStringArray;

    public IEnumerator GetAllVehicles()
    {
        WWW VehicleData = new WWW ("http://localhost/CMVM/LoadVehicle.php"); 
        yield return VehicleData;

        Debug.Log (VehicleData.text);
        string TheVehicleData = VehicleData.text;
                              The information comes back just fine.     
        if(TheVehicleData[TheVehicleData.Length - 1] == '/')
        { 
        TheVehicleData.TrimEnd('/');      Here I'm removing the delimiter
        }
        string[] results = TheVehicleData.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++) 
       {
        Debug.Log (results[i]);
       }
        VehicleStringArray = results; The results go back into an array

        VehicleIndexList = VehicleStringArray.Select(sArr => new VehicleIndex 
        {
            ID=VehicleStringArray[0],
            Make=VehicleStringArray[1],
            Model=VehicleStringArray[2],
            Year=VehicleStringArray[3],
            Mileage=VehicleStringArray[4]
        }).ToList();


    }
```

It looks like it should work only it gives the error: The type `VehicleIndex' does not contain a constructor that takes`0' arguments
What am I missing? Do I need to add something to the class? A list? an array?
Thanks for the help! I REALLY appreciate it.

ADDITIONAL-
Added an object initializer

```
public VehicleIndex Vi;
```

Then changed the lambda expression to

```
VehicleIndexList = VehicleStringArray.Select(sArr => new VehicleIndex 
    {
        Vi.ID==VehicleStringArray[0],
        Vi.Make==VehicleStringArray[1],
        Vi.Model==VehicleStringArray[2],
        Vi.Year==VehicleStringArray[3],
        Vi.Mileage==VehicleStringArray[4]
    }).ToList();
```

The only way to avoid the red line was to use the double equal. I'm not sure if this is right, since it is still not working, I'm guessing not.

Comment: Well, does `VehicleIndex` have a constructor that does not have any arguments? If not you could either create one or call a constructor within your `Select` projection.

Comment: Whoops, posted the wrong class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a constructor that takes all of the properties as arguments; just use that instead of the object initializer:

```
    VehicleIndexList = VehicleStringArray.Select(sArr => new VehicleIndex 
    (
        VehicleStringArray[0],
        VehicleStringArray[1],
        VehicleStringArray[2],
        VehicleStringArray[3],
        VehicleStringArray[4]
    )).ToList();
```

Note, however, that contructors typically only need paramaters that are *required* for the object to function properly. If the property values are not required, there's nothing wrong with removing the constructor and using initialization syntax (`new VehicleIndex { }`) instead.

Comment: So something like: VehicleIndex Vi= new VehicleIndex(param1,param2, param3, etc);                                                                                                   Then in the lambda Vi.ID=VehicleSt4ringArray[0]. etc... Am I in the ball park D? If not, please break it down, lambdas and WWW arrays are new to me.

Comment: Very confused now. Getting an error: A field or property `VehicleIndex' cannot be initialized with a collection object initializer because type `VehicleIndex' does not implement `System.Collections.IEnumerable' interface

Comment: Nor sure why you added `public VehicleIndex Vi;` and changed the query the way that you did. If you just change the lambda to the syntax I gave you it should work fine. Either that or remove the constructor you have.

Comment: My apologies. This is still new to me. I'll make the change and let you know.

Comment: It just compiled! Thanks so much!

Comment: D- One more question. When I ran the program, it gave me an index out of range error. Any thoughts on where I messed up?

Comment: @KenGordon Most likely you have a string that does not have 5 parts when split, but you'd have to look at the data to be sure.

Comment: Thanks so much D!

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same thing as JavaScript's join()

[String.Join Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)